# How can we overcome the missing muted/volume property on HTML5 video on UiWebView/iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, video, volume

As many hybrid app developers know, Apple has decided to disallow setting the volume property of HTML5 video elements in JavaScript. This also amounts to the the muted property. The concept of muted videos which autoplay when scrolled into view and with the option of unmuting on tap is growing increasingly popular (pioneered by Vine, Facebook, etc.). I'm trying to find a way around this limitation in design. From what I've been able to read on the subject, there's not any hack or solution that solves this design requirement of mine.

Here's my thoughts so far:

- I could split the audio from the video into a separate stream and sync current time with the video and call play() when the user is tapping. However, iOS Safari/UiWebView does not support simultaneous audio/video streams. Thus, this is simply not an option.
- I could encode two videos, one with sound and one without. I could then swap the src on tap. However, this requires reloading the entire stream and also nearly doubles the amount of data required. The latency is noticeable. Thus, this won't be a viable solution.
- I could embed a native AVPlayer class element in the webview. However, this would be an overlay and not be manageable from within the webview. Custom controls and UI interaction from within the dom would not be possible. Thus, this is not an option.
- I could simply disable the output of the app and dynamically switch it on whenever the user taps a video element. However, to my knowledge this is not possible. I could show the native software volume slider, but that would defeat the purpose of this whole thing.

Do you have any suggestions or ways around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an acceptable solution. I split the videos into three files. One without audio, one without video and then one with both video and audio for desktop browsers/Android.

It seems like running simultaneous streams CAN work as long as they doesn't conflict with each other, which basically means a separate audiotrack and a video with no audio Channels play just fine in unison.